# Is there a way to break out of Update() function

Tags: unity-game-engine

So, I'm trying to make my own movement script for Unity with a Rigidbody component attached to my character, and I'm using this code inside of the update function:

```
// Up above, in public scope, before Start and Update functions
public float speed = 1f;
public Rigidbody body;

void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow())) { // Left arrow key
        body.AddForce(transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

My problem is, since it's inside of the Update() function, it keeps going, it keeps turning, even if I don't have the key pressed.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? I have tried taking away Time.deltaTime but Brackeys said you use it so that it's frame rate dependent, so if you have a higher frame rate it doesn't turn faster, and same with a low frame rate, you turn slower. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use a boolean to toggle the running of `update` ...

Comment: @V.Sambor Thanks for the quick reply, I tried that, but it didn’t fix it. Thanks.

Comment: `it keeps turning` what do you mean? You add a force in a certain direction there is no `turning` happening in your code. It will keep moving into this direction since you never take away force.. that's how physics work .. Note in general: You should separate the getting user Input (-> `Update`) and the adding forces (-> `FixedUpdate`)

Answer (score 1):

It keeps turning even after releasing the key? Yep that's what `AddForce` will do.
After you apply a force to an object it will continue to move based on that force uless it has drag or an opposing force is applied. Go into the rigidbody to set the drag or create a script that applies an opposing force once you stop pressing the button.

If you put a `Debug.Log` within the `if` statement you will see it is not called every frame but only when you have the button held down.
And last, I don't think that your keycode should have `()` after `LeftArrow`, does this not produce an error?

Answer (score 0):

> An object in motion stays in motion with the same speed and in the
>   same direction unless acted upon by an unbalanced force.
>   
>                                                                                                                                  ---- Isaac Newton

So if you want to stop the object, you can do:

1. Add an oppsite force

   ```
   if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow())) {
       ...
   } else if (!body.IsSleeping()) {
       body.AddForce(-body.velocity * factor);
   }
   ```
2. Give a drag value

   ```
   body.drag = dragValue;
   ```

Comment: or hard set the `velocity` to `0`

Answer (score 0):

You have two questions, one on the title and another one on the description.

**For the title one:**

The only way to stop/break Update() cycle is to disable the script, like this:

```
enabled = false;
```

**For the description one:**

You have to stop the force applied to the object (as the rest of the answers exemplify).
You can apply an opposite force, or just set velocity to 0.

```
 rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
```

Comment: you don't set `speed to 0` this is phrased a bit confusing since `speed` is a field used by OP ;)

Comment: @derHugo you were totally right, edited, thanks buddy!